# Speed up CSV reading code (vector of doubles)

Tags: java, parsing, csv, io

I am trying to read a single-columned CSV of doubles into `Java` with a string header. It is 11 megabytes and takes over 15 minutes to read, which is clearly unacceptable. In `R` this CSV would take about 3 seconds to load.

This CSV file may contain strings so I am parsing it with this in mind.

The CSV reading method needs to return `Vector<Double>` due to reliance on this output by other parts of the application.

The issue is not due to the `isNumber` static method, since each call to that is taking `200 nanoseconds`, thus contributing approximately 0.2 seconds to the 15 minutes of parsing time.

The `Double.valueOf()` only takes about 500 nanoseconds, so it is not that either.

`csvData.add()` is only taking 80 nanoseconds so it is not that.

```
private static Vector<Double> readTXTFileSingle(String csvFileName) throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader stream = null;
    Vector<Double> csvData = new Vector<Double>();

    try {
        stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            if( ! NumberUtils.isNumber(splitted[0])) {

                continue;
            }

            Double dataLine = Double.valueOf(splitted[0]);
            csvData.add(dataLine);

        }
    } finally {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.close();
    }
    return csvData;
}
```

Comment: How is `NumberUtils.isNumber` implemented?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg This is responsible for 200 milliseconds of the lag (200 nanoseconds per call, 1,000,000 times). So it is not the problem

Comment: I'd still like to see it, if you're willing to provide it.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It's open source `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils`. I didn't read the method because it's very long. But can confirm a consistent 60-300 nanoseconds, holding aside accidental garbage collection within the nanoTime() window.

Comment: Wait a moment, you profiled it but do not know where it is slow?

Comment: @Bobby Profiled a bit of it. Running other tests now.

Comment: Run a profiler on it...I mean, yes, we are doing reviews for performance improvements, but we do not do guess work. Please run it through a profiler and see what takes that long, then add that information to the question.

Comment: But my first guess would be the resizing of the `Vector`. Creating it with an appropriate default capacity should help.

Comment: It takes 1.2 seconds to read a 85MB CSV file on my machine. What's your input look like?

Comment: @palacsint Are they all doubles?

Comment: A sample line: `111.23456789,88,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`. The file contains it one million times.

Comment: May I ask what is your environment? (JVM version, OS, CPU, memory)

Comment: As @bowmore pointed out, you must have something else going on. You have accepted 'my' answer... did it help? How much? What else is happening in your code? The suggestions I gave are not enough to fix a 15-minute problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Bobby's comment, Vector is your problem, but not for the reason he says...

Vector is a **synchronized** class. Each call to any method on Vector will lock the thread, flush all cache lines, and generally waste a lot of time (in a situation where it's usage is in a single thread only).

The fact that you use Vector indicates that you are running some really old code, or you have not properly [read the JavaDoc for it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

A secondary performance problem is that each value is being converted to a `Double` Object. In cases where you have large amounts of data, and where there is a primitive available for you to use, it is always faster to use the primitive (in this case, `double` instead of `Double`).

You should also be using the Java7 try-with-resources mechanism for your `stream`.

My recommendation is to change the signature of your method to return a List... actually, no, my recommendation is to return an array of primitive `double[]`.... if you are interested in speed, this will be a significant improvement:

```
private static double[] readTXTFileSingle(String csvFileName) throws IOException {
    double[] csvData = new double[4096]; // arbitrary starting size.
    int dcnt = 0;

    try (BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            if( ! NumberUtils.isNumber(splitted[0])) {

                continue;
            }

            double dataLine = Double.parseDouble(splitted[0]);
            if (dcnt >= csvData.length) {
                // add 50% to array size.
                csvData = Arrays.copyOf(csvData, dcnt + (dcnt / 2));
            }
            csvData[dcnt++] = dataLine;

        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(csvData, dcnt);
}
```

### Edit:

One other thing, if you want another tweak in performance, use:

```
String[] splitted = line.split(",", 2);
```

since you never access more than the first field in the record, you do not need to look for comma's beyond the first comma

Comment: "Vector is a synchronized class." Ah, now I understand that odd "You shouldn't use that but I can't remember why" feeling I had.

Comment: I doubt `Vector`'s synchronization is responsible for a 15 minute run on an 11M file. I've tried this code (with `Vector` in place) on a local file and it consistently returned in under 1 second.

Comment: @bowmore you are right... by the way, did you run it with a pre-set vector size or did you let it grow? The OP must have something else going on

Comment: I've used the code as is in OP. I only supplied a very naive `isNumber()` implementation myself by basically calling `Double.parseDouble()` and catching the exception.

Comment: @bowmore: [IsNumber() could be one of the problems](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.java?view=markup), to me it looks rather heavy weight.

Comment: Just to make sure, I've run it with that implementation and if anything, it is even faster than my naive `isNumber()` implementation

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize the open source library [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to parse csv data to vector of doubles, as the library provides excellent performance with multi-threading, caching and optimized code.

Try the following lines of code with the help of this library:

```
private static Vector<Double> readTXTFileSingle(String csvFileName) throws IOException {
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(new CsvParserSettings());
    List<String[]> resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(csvFileName));
    Vector<Double> csvData = new Vector<Double>();

    for (String[] row : resolvedData) {
        if (!NumberUtils.isNumber(row[0])) {
            continue;
        }

        csvData.add(Double.valueOf(row[0]));
    }

    return csvData;
}
```